# Typed Dataset: Can't change connection String

Tags: c#, connection, dataset, connection-string, tableadapter

I use typed datasets in my solution (they are defined in an other project, I have only references). I want to change the Connection String at runtime.
I have tried the following, but didnt work:

```
MyDatasetTableAdapters.MyDataTableAdapter adapter = new MyDataTableAdapter();
adapter.Connection=MySQLConnection;
```

same with

```
adapter.Connection.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString;
```

There is no definition for Connection.

Is there an easy way to change the connection?

Thank you!

Comment: adapter.SelectCommand.Connection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ConnectionModifier in your MyDatasetTableAdapters to Public (the default is Internal), then you can set the ConnectionString for the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any exceptions?

```
adapter.Connection.ConnectionString = [your connection string];
```

This should work though what are you trying to set it to? It should be a string.

if the connection string you want to set it to is a property of the project try

```
adapter.Connection.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.[YourPropertyNameHere];
```

or if you just want to set it as a string use

```
adapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "YourConnectionStringHere";
```